# Limit Github slack integration to only reviews to which I'm assigned or participating

Tags: github, slack

Has anyone figured out how to limit Github slack integration to only reviews in which you are assigned or a reviewer?

I added it to my slack workspace and set the subscriptions thus:

/github subscribe myOrg statuses, reviews

I was hoping to only get my reviews and not all reviews.  I can't seem to figure out how to filter down to the items I care about especially as the notification options are: every new message or none.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Install the [GitHub Slack integration](https://github.com/integrations/slack#configuration) in your workspace
2. Go to your [github settings reminders](https://github.com/settings/reminders)
3. Enable real-time alerts and check the appropriate boxes (which is probably all but `Your PR has failed CI checks`)

In slack you do not need to subscribe to anything.  Doing so will get you all kinds of additional notifications